# Возможно ли изменить стили iframe модуля?

Tags: html, iframe, css

Ифреймится кусок "бронирования номеров", примерно так:

```
<iframe id="bookingFrame" style="BORDER-TOP-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-LEFT-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-BOTTOM-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-RIGHT-WIDTH: 0px" border="0" frameborder="0" src="http://www.travelline.ru/booking/hotel/50/" width="700" height="1150"></iframe>
```

Я знаю что это всё устарело и неправильно, но к сожалению должно быть именно так :(
Можно ли повлиять как то на внутренние стили этого ифрейма? Как минимум сменить цветовую гамму? (прописывать одинаковые стили в моём CSS не помогает, !important не помогает, может есть ещё варианты? ) Спасибо за внимание.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если домены разные, то [нельзя](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0).